# Upgrading Windows 10 home to institutional Pro via the institutional volume licensing server

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, license

I bought a laptop with Windows 10 Home. Our university has a licensing server that maintains Windows 10 Pro.

The question is whether and how I can upgrade to Windows 10 Pro **without formatting the disk** and installing the institutional version.

By licensing server I mean that if our IT formats the disk and installs Windows 10 Pro from their CD, then every half a year I need to execute the following commands:

```
slmgr -skms 123.123.123.123 (some IP that they provide)
slmgr -ato
```

However, they do not have any product key in the form XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX, so I cannot just change the key. I tried to give the commands above under existing Windows 10 Home, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: If you don’t have a product key then you cannot upgrade your Home install to Professional.  There must be a product key associated, you might not be told it, be there is one.

Comment: “Change product key” and use the Windows 10 Pro generic key. You can easily find it on the internet.  This will upgrade it to pro. Activation is up to you after that.

Comment: @Appleoddity - The generic Windows 10 Professional license key cannot be used to activate the installation nor will it work in a VLK configuration.

Comment: @Ramhound of course not, that’s kind of obvious. But it will upgrade the installation to pro. At that point KMS activation should be an option.